# Difference between probabilities in R and Python (XGBoost)

Tags: python, r, model, classification, xgboost

I am trying to run under `Python .model` `XGboost` `binary classifier` from `R`.

I have the exact order and encoding for all of the features. I have checked it 100 times. The used code is as follows:

```
bst = xgb.Booster() #init model

bst.load_model(path+"file.model") # load R model

features_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(features)

pred=bst.predict(features_dmatrix)
```

And I have some kind of strange situation in two aspects:

- the output from predict function is `p(y=0|x)`. I am just wondering why, because the R model i strained with two class (0 and 1) and it is tuned to predict "1" class;
- there are 3% of all cases with differences between `Python` (1-output) and `R` (original output). The difference in probabilities are: min=-0.1846033; max=0.0614451.

Could you please give me some kind of experience, explanation or advice how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Random states are used in ML models. Unless you can make the random states are identical between Python and R(And I don't think it's possible), the results will never be the same.

Comment: Thank you @yifyan, do you have some explanation for the first issue with p(y=0|x), instead of p(y=1|x). Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's 0 or 1. You should have the labels available. It's best to check the documentation of the model you use.